# db.SaveChanges not committing changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am connected with the ado.net entity model. I can retrieve information from the database using the Dropdownlist, but I am not able to commit changes (Insert) into the database. It previously works fine two days ago, but just stop working today. I have tried every trick in similar topics but no changes.

My Controlller:

```
public class RimySaleController : Controller
{
    // GET: RimySale
    // dropdownlist

    public ActionResult RimSaleIndex()
    {

        newLayanDBEntities17 db = new newLayanDBEntities17();
        List<Rim> list = db.Rims.ToList();
        ViewBag.RimName = new SelectList(list, "rim_id", "rim_name");

        List<Employee> lists = db.Employees.ToList();
        ViewBag.EmpName = new SelectList(lists, "emp_id", "emp_name");

        List<Customer> listp = db.Customers.ToList();
        ViewBag.CustName = new SelectList(listp, "cust_id", "cust_name");

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RimSaleSave(RimSale model)
    {
        try
        {
            newLayanDBEntities17 db = new newLayanDBEntities17();
            Rim_Sale addRim = new Rim_Sale();

            addRim.Date = model.Date;
            addRim.cust_int = model.Cust_int;
            addRim.emp_id = model.Emp_id;
            addRim.rim_id = model.Rim_id;
            addRim.rim_sold_quantity = model.Rim_sold_quantity;
            addRim.rim_sold_unit_price = model.Rim_sold_unit_price;

            //making the changes
            db.Rim_Sale.Add(addRim);
            db.SaveChanges();
         }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

        return RedirectToAction("RimSaleIndex");
    }

    }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBattSale", "BatterySale", FormMethod.Post))
{
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Sold_date, new { @type = "Date", @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bat_id, ViewBag.BattName as SelectList, "--Select Battery--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Batt_sold_quantity, new { @type = "number", @placeholder = "Type Quantity Sold", @class = "form-control " })
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Batt_unit_price, new { @placeholder = "Price Paid for One Battery", @type = "number", @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cust_id, ViewBag.CustName as SelectList, "--Select Customer--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Emp_id, ViewBag.EmpName as SelectList, "--Select Employee--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            <input type="Submit" value=" Submit" />  <input type="reset" value=" Reset" />
            <br />

 }
```

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: what is after try catch block? please share whole `RimSaleSave` method

Comment: This issue can be because you are using a single database object.

Comment: @Simonare I post the whole method. Thanks

Comment: @RahulPawar it returns no error. The changes (db.Savechanges) is not just committed into database

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN Could you please share the exception information ?

Comment: Could you show, please, your connection string?

Comment: @stepup here is  my connection string for the entity model: <add name="newLayanDBEntities17" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Modela.csdl|res://*/Models.Modela.ssdl|res://*/Models.Modela.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source= server name;initial catalog=newLayanDB;user id=[username];password=[password];multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN how did you test this code? How do you know there's a problem in the first place? Did you debug this code? Does `model` contain any values? If `model` is full of 0s, you may find a lot of "empty" rows in the database. Did you try using SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see what's sent to the server? The code has some issues by the way - that `try/catch` is meaningless and the context is *not* enclosed in a `using` block.

Comment: are you sure you are checking the right database? maybe the insert is committing to a different database and you are checking in a different database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok. Try another one approach to insert data:

```
using (var db = new YourEntities()) 
{ 
    Rim_Sale addRim = new Rim_Sale();

    addRim.Date = model.Date;
    addRim.cust_int = model.Cust_int;
    addRim.emp_id = model.Emp_id;
    addRim.rim_id = model.Rim_id;
    addRim.rim_sold_quantity = model.Rim_sold_quantity;
    addRim.rim_sold_unit_price = model.Rim_sold_unit_price;

    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Rim_Sale] ON");
    //making the changes
    db.Rim_Sale.Add(addRim);
    db.SaveChanges()
    db.Entry(addRim).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Rim_Sale] OFF");
}
```

If data is not inserted, then there is a chance that you are inserting data to another database. If you use localDb, then make sure that a property of `.mdf` file in your solution as Copy to output Directory: "Copy only if newer", otherwise your db file will overwrite every time it runs.

UPDATE:

It is not a good way, but give a try:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
   "Insert into Rim_Sale Values(@Date, @cust_int, @emp_id, @rim_id, 
        @rim_sold_quantity , @rim_sold_unit_price )",
    new SqlParameter("Date", Date),
    new SqlParameter("cust_int", cust_int),
    new SqlParameter("emp_id", emp_id),
    new SqlParameter("rim_id", rim_id),
    new SqlParameter("rim_sold_quantity ", rim_sold_quantity ),
    new SqlParameter("rim_sold_unit_price ", rim_sold_unit_price ),
);
```

Comment: My database is on Azure server. May that cause an issue?

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN could you try write the following script at Azure SQL db? Insert test data into table where you want to pull in your application. `INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES (...)` and see whether your data pulled from the server? This gives to us information whether we use the right connection to our database.

Comment: I run the insert script on Azure query tool and it looks like I have to always set the "insert identity" to ON before I can be able to insert value. I am thinking that this might be the issue. I don't need to set it to On SSMS tho.  Might this be the issue?

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN try to put `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Rim_Sale] ON");` in code. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN After inserting data into db, then is it possible to see your new inserted value in your application?

Comment: still no changes. Please is there a way or recommendation to insert data into multiple table apart from this way. through my research online, I see that `db.savechanges()` is a common issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN have you tried to insert your data into dB through Azure? Have you seen the newly added data in your application?

Comment: Yes, I see the new data added. But doesn't work through the code in VS

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN are you adding data into multiple tables or multiple records into one table? Could you post the whole code?

Comment: Am adding data into one table, but the table has a foreign key in it from another table

Comment: it is really strange beaviour? No exceptions? try to insert with null into foreign keys

Comment: Not still inserting. I think am convince that issue is the  ado.net entity model data I imported. It works well with normal connectionstring. Thanks.

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN In my view, that error is something simple and not with EF. The above code should work.  Feel free to upvote if you feel that it was helpful:)